# Is it possible to create and fill programmatically an AutoCompleteTextView in android?

Tags: android, view, autofill, programmatically-created

I've few weeks of experience with android and I'd like to create and fill programmatically an AutoCompleteTextView but I can't because the Activity stops.
This is the code I wrote:

```
    public class ItemEditor extends LinearLayout {
  String[]  itemList = { "one", "two", "three" };

  public ItemEditor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.makeEditor(context);
  }

  void makeEditor(Context context) {
    AutoCompleteTextView item = new AutoCompleteTextView(context);
    item.setId(View.generateViewId());

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
        item.getId(), itemList);

    item.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);

    this.addView(item);
  }
}
```

and I use it as follows:

```
public class ItemEditorActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_set_editor);
    this.setContentView(new MessageSetEditor(this));
  }
...
}
```

As soon as I try to show ItemEditorActivity, it stops.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself: in the array adapter declaration I used the id of the autocomplete widget instead of **android.R.layout.select_dialog_item**.